# Records created using LWC not getting populated with information

Tags: lightning-web-components, modal, create-records

I am creating a pop-up modal to create new records for a custom object Student__c using LWC. When I am clicking on the Save button a record is getting created but the fields are all blank.

.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Create a Student Record?">


        <lightning-button variant="brand"
        label="New"
        title="Open Modal"
        onclick={customShowModalPopup}
        class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
    
      
    <template if:true={customFormModal}>
    
        <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
               
                <header class="slds-modal__header">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" title="Close" onclick={customHideModalPopup}>
                <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close"
                    alternative-text="close"
                    variant="inverse"
                    size="small" ></lightning-icon>
                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
                </button>
                    <h2 class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">New Student</h2>
                </header>
           
    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium">
    
        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12 slds-p-horizontal--medium slds-m-bottom_medium">
                <lightning-input label="Name" value={StuName} onchange={handleNameChange}></lightning-input>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12 slds-p-horizontal--medium slds-m-bottom_medium">
                <lightning-input label="Phone" value={StuPhone} onchange={handlePhoneChange}></lightning-input>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12 slds-p-horizontal--medium slds-m-bottom_medium">
                <lightning-input label="Email" value={StuEmail} onchange={handleEmailChange}></lightning-input>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12 slds-p-horizontal--medium slds-m-bottom_medium">
                <lightning-input label="Address" value={StuAddress} onchange={handleAddressChange}></lightning-input>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12 slds-p-horizontal--medium slds-m-bottom_medium">
                <lightning-input label="Class" value={StuClass} onchange={handleClassChange}></lightning-input>
            </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
        <button class="slds-button slds-button--destructive" onclick={customHideModalPopup}>Cancel</button>
        <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick={handleForSave}>Save</button>
    </footer>
</div>
</div>
</section>
<div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open">
</div>
</template>  
</lightning-card>  
</template>
```

.js

```
import { LightningElement,track } from 'lwc';
import insertStud from '@salesforce/apex/modalNewStudent.insertStud';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
 
export default class ModalStudentCreate extends LightningElement {

    StuName;
    StuPhone;
    StuEmail;
    StuAddress;
    StuClass;
    @track stu ={};


    @track customFormModal = false; 
    
    customShowModalPopup() {            
        this.customFormModal = true;
    }
 
    customHideModalPopup() {    
        this.customFormModal = false;
    }
   
    handleNameChange(event){
        this.StuName = event.target.value;
        this.stu.StuName=this.StuName;
    }

    handlePhoneChange(event){
        this.StuPhone = event.target.value;
        this.stu.StuPhone=this.StuPhone;
    }

    handleEmailChange(event){
        this.StuEmail = event.target.value;
        this.stu.StuEmail=this.StuEmail;
    }

    handleAddressChange(event){
        this.StuAddress = event.target.value;
        this.stu.StuAddress=this.StuAddress;
    }

    handleClassChange(event){
        this.StuClass = event.target.value;
        this.stu.StuClass=this.StuClass;
    }

    handleForSave(){
    
        insertStud({ stuRec : this.stu})
        .then(result =>{
            this.StuName='';
            this.StuPhone='';
            this.StuEmail='';
            this.StuClass='';
            this.StuAddress='';
            this.toastEventFire('Success','Student Record is Saved','success');  
            this.customHideModalPopup();                
        })
        
    }

    toastEventFire(title,msg,variant,mode){
        const e = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: title,
            message: msg,
            variant: variant,
            mode: mode
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(e);
    }

}
```

Aura Class

```
public with sharing class modalNewStudent {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void insertStud(Student__c stuRec){
        
        insert stuRec;
    }
}
```

Apart from this issue when I am trying to open that blank record from the 'Recently Viewed' list view, it is opening but when I try to access that same record from the 'All' list view it does not open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the object you are sending is not mapped in salesforce. You need to send the api name of the fields as the student objects ('stu') attribute.

```
    import { LightningElement,track } from 'lwc';
    import insertStud from '@salesforce/apex/modalNewStudent.insertStud';
    import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
    

export default class ModalStudentCreate  extends LightningElement {

    StuName;
    StuPhone;
    StuEmail;
    StuAddress;
    StuClass;
    @track stu ={};


    @track customFormModal = false; 
    
    customShowModalPopup() {            
        this.customFormModal = true;
    }

    customHideModalPopup() {    
        this.customFormModal = false;
    }

    handleNameChange(event){
        this.StuName = event.target.value;
        this.stu.Student_Name__c=this.StuName;
    }

    handlePhoneChange(event){
        this.StuPhone = event.target.value;
        this.stu.Student_Phone__c=this.StuPhone;
    }

    handleEmailChange(event){
        this.StuEmail = event.target.value;
        this.stu.Email__c=this.StuEmail;
    }

    handleAddressChange(event){
        this.StuAddress = event.target.value;
        this.stu.StuAddress=this.StuAddress;
    }

    handleClassChange(event){
        this.StuClass = event.target.value;
        this.stu.Class__c=this.StuClass;
    }

    handleForSave(){
    
        insertStud({ stuRec : this.stu})
        .then(result =>{
            this.StuName='';
            this.StuPhone='';
            this.StuEmail='';
            this.StuClass='';
            this.StuAddress='';
            this.toastEventFire('Success','Student Record is Saved','success');  
            this.customHideModalPopup();                
        })
        
    }

    toastEventFire(title,msg,variant,mode){
        const e = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: title,
            message: msg,
            variant: variant,
            mode: mode
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. That was the issue and the new record that is getting created does have the values I filled up but the record is only accessible from only Recently Viewed list view.

Comment: @NightGuy maybe you have some filters on the list view can you check that?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. The problem got solved automatically later that day after I logged out and logged in.